# FreeBSD: pkg_delete -a by accident. How to restore?

Tags: freebsd, pkg-resources

I have accidently ran "pkg_delete -a" on FreeBSD 9.1 .
Is there anyway to restore this operation or revert backwards?

And if not, is there some way to copy the pkg installed on another server?  (there are basically 4 servers that are alike they all contain the same packages, this operation only performed on one of them).

Answer (score 0):

You could try [bpkg](http://www.freshports.org/ports-mgmt/bpkg) script to generate binary packages for all installed programs. See documentation for `-b/-B` options.